# Const cannot define in react

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I cannot define const in react.

After start the web browser, I got the error when I type `accounts` in console command.

```
>accounts
VM768:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: accounts is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM768:1
```

I thought this is `Web3` error, so I defined `accounts` in console command.
However I could define `accounts`.

```
>const accounts = web3.eth.accounts[0]
<undefined

>accounts
<"0xeb827c448545--------1a7d5ced86ac3"
```

I want to show the address by `this.state.account`.

Could you give me any advise, please?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  conponentWillmount() {
    this.loadBlockchainData()
  }

  async loadBlockchainData() {
    const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "http://localhost:7545")
    const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
    console.log("network:", network)
    const accounts = await web3.eth.accounts[0]
    this.state({ account: accounts[0]}) 
    console.log("account:", accounts[0])
    // Fetch Account
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { account: ''}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <p>Your account : {this.state.account} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you paste code of "./web3" file ?

Comment: `const accounts = await web3.eth.accounts[0]` from `loadBlockchainData` is local. You cannot access it from console.

Comment: @estus I used console in local.

Comment: @estus I edited my code a little bit.

Comment: Which version of react do you use?

Comment: @Ywzx I`m using 16.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const accounts = await web3.eth.accounts[0]` variable is local to `loadBlockchainData` method. It cannot be accessed from console command line because only globals are accessible from there.

In case `accounts` needs to be debugged in browser dev tools, a breakpoint can be set up inside `loadBlockchainData`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand that cannot be accessible.
Then, how do I show my account in frontend?

Comment: By setting it to a state. You have a typo, `this.state({ account: accounts[0]})`, it should be `this.setState`.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my typo, but account still doesn't show in front. Is there any problem?

Comment: There don't seem to be any. You don't handle errors in loadBlockchainData and you didn't mention if there's expected console.log output. Any way, if this.setState call is reached, it's expected to update the component and show it in this.state.account .